# Creating / Getting a Cloud Run Job using the Python API Client Library

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-api-python-client

I created a Cloud Run Job using command line:

```
gcloud --verbosity=debug beta run jobs create my-job \
--image=us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/job:latest
```

When I can list the jobs using the  API Client library, `my-job` is returned:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
with googleapiclient.discovery.build('run', 'v1') as client:
    request = client.namespaces().jobs().list(parent=f'namespaces/my-project')
    response = request.execute()
    print(response)
```

However, when I try to `get` the job using the following snippet, I get 404 "Requested entity was not found":

```
...
request = client.namespaces().jobs().get(name='namespaces/my-project/jobs/my-job')
response = request.execute()
...
```

I am also unable to create a job using the following snippet, this again return 404 "Requested entity was not found":

```
request = client.namespaces().jobs().create(parent=f'namespaces/my-project',
     body={
        "metadata": {
           "name": "my-job2",
         },
        "spec": {
           "template": {
               "spec": {
                   "template": {
                       "spec": {
                          "containers": [{
                             "image": "us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/job:latest"
                           }],
                        }
                      }
                    }
                }
           },
        })
```

I have Cloud Run Admin permissions for the project.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it working fine when you are [running it locally](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local)?

Comment: I am not sure how this can help? I am using (for now) the sample container provided in Cloud Run documentation.

Comment: Does this [article](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/jobs/build-create-python) help you?

Comment: @MousumiRoy thank you, but not really, this gives instructions for executing using CLI, which works, I am trying to use the API Client Library to start it from code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into the API reference, it appears you are using the call correctly [1](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.jobs/get), [2](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.jobs/listhttps://). When doing the get call, you need to specify the correct [regional endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest#regional-endpoints). So, it might happen that you are using the [global endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest#global-endpoint) for the list, create and get calls. However, make sure that you use the regional endpoint for the get and create call.

The global endpoint has this documentation for v1[4](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest#global-endpoint): "For v1, this endpoint only supports Global List: use regional endpoints instead."

You can see an example using this command from cloud shell. (This assumes your region is 'us-central1', if not that needs to be updated).

curl -X GET 
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) 
https://us-central1-run.googleapis.com/apis/run.googleapis.com/v1/namespaces/my-project/jobs/my-job

curl -X GET 
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) 
https://run.googleapis.com/apis/run.googleapis.com/v1/namespaces/my-project/jobs/my-job

Comment: I have posted an answer. Can you check if that is helpful?

Comment: @Monosumi Roy Thank you that was exactly the problem.

Comment: How is this not said clearly in the documentation for the cloud run endpoints? Seriously I just spent several hours trying to list the jobs because I was trying to use the global endpoint. Thanks a lot Mousumi Roy!